# MonoTouch, test if remote device is found on local network

Tags: networking, xamarin.ios, reachability

I am using MonoTouch to develop an app which will connect to remote devices on a network. These devices have data which can be access through http queries.

If I provide a valid IP address to a controller the app works perfectly, however it hangs for a long time if the controller is not on the network. For this reason I thought it would be good to use the Reachability.cs class which can be found here:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

Instead of using google.com as the host, I am using the IP address of the controller. I have read that there is a bug with this class which causes it to not like having "http" at the beginning of the URL. Having now tried numerous things to get this working I am out of ideas.

Do anyone have any suggestions? Perhaps I am reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 2):

> Having now tried numerous things to get this working I am out of ideas.

From your question it's not clear what issue you're having with the `Reachability` class. Maybe you could edit it and add more details ? e.g. what you tried so far, how it reacts like: never works, throws/crash, inconsistent results ...

> Do anyone have any suggestions?

If your main issue is **blocking** the UI of your application then you could (and should anyway) do your connection and data transfer asynchronously (or a separate thread) and once completed update your UI (from the main thread).

E.g. using [WebClient.DownloadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144190.aspx)